# Integrating npm module into a plain Javascript app, don't know how to fix error

Tags: javascript, npm, capacitor, rollup

I apologize, my lack of knowledge of how to build modern Javascript apps is showing.

We have a Capacitor app that uses plain Javascript, without any build tools. This works fine. We're trying to add Microsoft Code Push support, via https://github.com/mapiacompany/capacitor-codepush, and we're running into a problem with how to integrate it into our app.

For Capacitor and its plugins, we use  tags to include the plugin.js files from the various node_modules/.../dist directories.

If we do this with node_modules/capacitor-codepush/dist/plugin.js, we get an error about missing acquisitionSdk. Including node_modules/code-push/script/acquisition-sdk.js doesn't help.

Ok, so maybe there are a bunch of dependencies? We tried using rollup to see if we could get that to work, but cannot. Using this simple input file:

```
import { codePush } from 'capacitor-codepush';

console.log("hello");
```

we get `[!] Error: Invalid value "iife" for option "output.format" - UMD and IIFE output formats are not supported for code-splitting builds.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is a plain JavaScript app? How do you run it?

Comment: By plain javascript app, I'm just talking about a single .js file, no transcoding, no nothing. This is being run by Capacitor, but I think the problem I have above is more generic than that. For the code push project, how can I include/package it with just that 2 line sample javascript file so that it executes without missing objects or other errors.

Comment: @MarkFletcher If the problem is more generic, can you provide some more generic (and minimal, if possible) representation of the problem with code? e.g. Create a repo, gist or fiddle and guidelines on how to run (if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I was able to get it working was to switch to using `webpack`. For reasons I don't understand, my initial attempts using `rollup` did not work. `webpack` was the key.

Answer (score -1):

You should run the `dist` version of your app. Meaning, you should use a bundler like `webpack`. Unbundled (pure) code can't use these features.

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried using rollup along with that 2 line input file. How would webpack be different?

Comment: Sometimes, it becomes a headache to bundle up popular libraries in js like axios with rollup because of the configurations and plugins. Requires some research, extra plugins which might lead to alot of work. Thats why webpack has been the standard bundler for many years with Parcel following up atm. @MarkFletcher